# Buffer discrepancies

Tags: qgis, buffer, measurements

I have created a 1 km buffer around a polygon using Geoprocessing Tools in order to identify local sites which lie within 1 km. However, whilst one local site is showing as being within 1 km of my polygon, when I measure the distance using the Measure Line tool, the closest distance that I make it is 1,064 m, so why is it included in the buffer?

Is it a smoothing error, is the Measure Line tool not as accurate?

I am currently working in EPSG:27700.

Comment: This link may help you (all the 'Measuring' part): http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/es/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#measuring
You may need to reproject your CRS.